# jQuery file upload; Limit types and size

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, upload, alert

I'm using the jQuery File Upload library and it works great for my needs. However I need the script to alert the user when they try to upload a file bigger than 64 megabyte. I have this line in my JS and that works perfectly;

```
if(data.files[0]['type'] != 'image/jpg' && data.files[0]['type'] != 'image/jpeg'){ alert("Only .jpg accepted. Please try using a accepted file type."); return; }
```

This works perfectly for not letting the users upload other than .jpg files. On the line after this code, I'm trying to add the following, but it doesn't work;

```
if(data.files[0]['size'] > (3*1024*1024)){ alert("The file you are trying to upload is too big. Please do not upload files bigger than 3mb."); return; }
```

When I try to upload files bigger than 3mb I'm still getting the alert about just .jpg are accepted and not the alert about the file size being too big. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try putting them in a nested if..else condition. Do you want the code to check first the image file type then check its size? If so, then put them in a nested if condition.

Comment: Thanks. How do I do that? So what you are saying is that my code is correct, but I need to put into a nested condition?

Comment: Yup! try this `if(data.files[0]['type'] != 'image/jpg' && data.files[0]['type'] != 'image/jpeg')
{ 
    alert("Only .jpg accepted. Please try using a accepted file type.");  return; 
} else if(data.files[0]['size'] > (3*1024*1024))
{ 
    alert("The file you are trying to upload is too big. Please do not upload files bigger than 3mb."); 
    return; 
}`

Comment: or this 
`if(data.files[0]['type'] != 'image/jpg' && data.files[0]['type'] != 'image/jpeg')
{ 
    alert("Only .jpg accepted. Please try using a accepted file type.");  if(data.files[0]['size'] > (3*1024*1024))
    { 
        alert("The file you are trying to upload is too big. Please do not    upload files bigger than 3mb."); 
        return; 
    }
} `